# Jquery selector - how can I ensure this works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some buttons, labelled logo1 - logo15 respectively.

There is another button called 'lets-go' that fires a function based on these buttons being selected - when you click a logo the class 'active'.

When there is no logo selected, I would like this button to not be in the DOM - and be hidden. At the moment, the 'active' class for the button brings it's opacity to 1.

I have this jquery statement at the moment.

```
  if (!$('.logo1, .logo2, .logo3, .logo4, .logo5, .logo6, .logo7, .logo8, .logo9, .logo10, .logo11, .logo12, .logo13, .logo14, .logo15').hasClass("active")) {
$('#lets-go').removeClass('active')};
```

But it's not working.

This is an example of one of my logoX buttons:

```
$('.logo15').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.logo15').toggleClass("active");
  $('#b15').toggleClass('alive');
  $('#b15').toggleClass('zoomTarget');
  $('#b15').toggleClass('dead');
  $('#lets-go').addClass('active');
  $('#popoutLetsGo').addClass('expand');
  $('.instructions-arrow-2').addClass('hide')
});
```

On click, they apply the class of 'active' to let's go. But it doesn't remove it, ever. Just if you click any of the 15 buttons a new button appears, but if you deselect the button it's still there - and then the next screen is blank.

Can you see why it's not?

I am basically looking for: If none of these classes have the class of active, then make sure this id doesn't have the class of active either.

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: *Can you see why it's not* - not with the tiny amount of code you've provided.     However:  if you **remove from the DOM** then you can't just "add it back" so easily - better to just `.hide()` it then you can `.show()` it later.  You'll need to include more code, such as how you hide/show the button, when you check, if you're using event delegation (and if the button is added/removed this will matter).   More importantly: what you mean by "**it's not working**" - is the button firing but not showing/hiding?  Is the button event not firing etc?

Comment: can you please provide little more  details.

Comment: Hey, I never remove the button from the DOM. It's hidden.

Comment: PS Don't use two classes (dead / alive) - use only CSS default styles and **just one** *active* className.

Comment: My comment above regarding "if you remove" matches the original question text: *"button to not be in the DOM"* - not be in the DOM = removed from the DOM

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following:

```
if (!$("[class*='logo']").hasClass("active")) {
  $('#lets-go').removeClass('active')};
}
```

This looks at the Class attribute for a item starting with `"logo"`, so `.logo3` would be one of those elements. But you may want to test each one.

```
$("[class*='logo']").each(function(i, el){
  if(!$(el).hasClass("active")){
      $('#lets-go').removeClass('active')};
    }
});
```

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function

You can also use simplified classes to help group selectors. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".logo").click(function() {
    $(".logo.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#letsgo").prop("disabled", false);
  });
  $("#letsgo").prop("disabled", true);
})
```

```css
.logo {
  padding: .4em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #999;
}

.active {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Make a Selection</p>
<div class="logo item-1">Logo 1</div>
<div class="logo item-2">Logo 2</div>
<div class="logo item-3">Logo 3</div>
<div class="logo item-4">Logo 4</div>
<div class="logo item-5">Logo 5</div>
<button id="letsgo">Let's Go!</button>
```

Comment: Never just do `"[class^='logo']"`, rather `"[class^='logo'], [class*=' logo']"`

Comment: Or even better wait for OP to show more code, perhaps `#parent .logo` would be a much better selector.

Comment: While worth considering (also consider adding `logo` (without numbers) to each logo), would be even easier.  This won't help OP as it's a) selects the same elements (assuming OPs HTML is as explained) and b) .hasClass already does the equivalent of .each

Comment: Also whydon't you just go for something like `const activeExists = $("#parent .active").length > 0`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan can you clarify why one would *never* use the Starts With selector in this scenario?

Comment: Hi, this solution didn't work. What additional details would you be requiring?

Comment: @Twisty sure: say you have `<div class="foo bar logo6 baz">` - the `^=` will fail, because it ***does not starts with***.

Comment: @AliShahVis please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the clarification, I see your point.

Comment: If all of the people complaining about the prematurity of the answer had voted to close the question as "Needs debugging information", the question would have been closed and the answer would not be present...

Comment: Never just use `"[class*='logo']"` rather `"[class^='logo'], [class*=' logo']"`

Comment: PS: instead of those 5 lines of `.each()` code you could simply : `$('#lets-go').toggleClass('active', $(".logo.active").length);` given such `.logo` exists